# Windows 7 only, IE only, thinks my website certificate has a problem?

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-7, ssl

I am getting this notice on WIN7 PCs only, with IE only.  Firefox is always fine, and IE on older windows versions seems to be fine.  It's blowing my mind, I have no clue why IE thinks there is a problem with the SSL cert.  Has anyone ever dealt with this before?

I do not wish to post the actual website address, because after-all - not ALL media is good media...

Thanks all.

```
There is a problem with this website's security certificate.

The security certificate presented by this website was not issued by a trusted certificate authority.

Security certificate problems may indicate an attempt to fool you or intercept any data you send to the server. 
We recommend that you close this webpage and do not continue to this website. 
 Click here to close this webpage. 

 Continue to this website (not recommended). 

More information

•  If you arrived at this page by clicking a link, check the website address in the address bar to be sure that it is the address you were expecting. 
•  When going to a website with an address such as https://example.com, try adding the 'www' to the address, https://www.example.com. 
•  If you choose to ignore this error and continue, do not enter private information into the website. 
For more information, see "Certificate Errors" in Internet Explorer Help.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that the root CA that signed your certificate isn't in the Trusted Root CA list in IE under Windows 7

Comment: You got me thinking - and I reinstalled the cert, maybe last time I didn't paste the intermediate CA but it's working now.  Thanks for the hint.